# column ambiguously defined in oracle apex?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have use this code as an interactive report sql query & toad and receive the same error, the idea is simply to join two tables :

```
select request.* from ( select distinct
  a.REQUEST_ID,
 (select full_name from  apps.per_all_people_f ppf where sysdate between effective_start_date 
 and effective_end_date and a.EMPLOYEE_NUMBER in (ppf.national_identifier,ppf.employee_number) 
 and current_employee_flag = 'Y' )   EMPLOYEE_NUMBER,
 a.DEPARTMENT,
 a.LOCATION,
 a.PROBLEM_TYPE,
 a.PROBLEM_PRIORITY,
 a.PROBLEM_SUMMARY,
 a.PROBLEM_DATE ,
 a.CREATED_BY ,
 a.CREATION_DATE,
 a.LAST_UPDATE_DATE,
 a.LAST_UPDATE_LOGIN,
 a.LAST_UPDATED_BY,
 a.STATUS,
 a.CLOSED_DATE,
 a.ASSIGNED_TO,
 a.EXTENSION,
 'Assign' as Assign,
 (select user_name from apps.fnd_user where user_id=a.created_by) Assigned_by       ,
 c.REQUEST_ID,
 c.FILENAME,
 c.MIME_TYPE,
 c.BLOB_CONTENT                
from IT_REQUESTS  a, IT_REQUESTS_ATTACH c
where 1=1
and a.request_source = 'IT'
and a.status                 = 'CLOSED'--'NEW'
and a.request_id = c.request_id
order by a.PROBLEM_DATE desc) request
```

error received:
**ORA-20999: Failed to parse SQL query! ORA-06550: line 10, column 4: ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined**

Comment: You have selected `a.REQUEST_ID` ***and*** `c.REQUEST_ID`.  You can't select two columns with the same name.

Comment: @MatBailie then how am I supposed to return records for the same request_id ?

Comment: You have `SELECT ..., a.REQUEST_ID, ..., c.REQUEST_ID, ... FROM a, c WHERE ... AND a.request_id = c.request_id` This shows that those two selected columns are not only the same name, but the same value.  Just select one of them, not both of them.

Comment: Generally queries of the form `select * from (select x, y, x from t)` can be simplified to `select x, y, x from t`. That would also let you include all the duplicate columns you want :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To illustrate what you did, I'll use Scott's sample schema.

This is a simple join between two tables; both of them contain `DEPTNO` column (as indicated) - no problem so far:

```
SQL> select e.deptno,   --> here
  2         e.ename,
  3         e.job,
  4         d.deptno,   --> and here
  5         d.dname
  6  from emp e join dept d on e.deptno = d.deptno
  7  where d.deptno = 10;

    DEPTNO ENAME      JOB           DEPTNO DNAME
---------- ---------- --------- ---------- --------------
        10 CLARK      MANAGER           10 ACCOUNTING
        10 KING       PRESIDENT         10 ACCOUNTING
        10 MILLER     CLERK             10 ACCOUNTING
```

This is your situation: you used such a query as a **subquery** (named it `request`). This won't work any more because - which `DEPTNO` is which?

```
SQL> select request.*
  2  from (select e.deptno,   --> here
  3               e.ename,
  4               e.job,
  5               d.deptno,   --> and here
  6               d.dname
  7        from emp e join dept d on e.deptno = d.deptno
  8        where d.deptno = 10
  9       ) request;
select request.*
               *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined


SQL>
```

---

What to do? As Mat commented, one option is to use only one of those columns, they have the same value anyway. Another one is to use **column aliases**:

```
SQL> select request.*
  2  from (select e.deptno as emp_deptno,    --> here
  3               e.ename,
  4               e.job,
  5               d.deptno as dept_deptno,   --> and here
  6               d.dname
  7        from emp e join dept d on e.deptno = d.deptno
  8        where d.deptno = 10
  9       ) request;

EMP_DEPTNO ENAME      JOB       DEPT_DEPTNO DNAME
---------- ---------- --------- ----------- --------------
        10 CLARK      MANAGER            10 ACCOUNTING
        10 KING       PRESIDENT          10 ACCOUNTING
        10 MILLER     CLERK              10 ACCOUNTING

SQL>
```

---

Generally speaking, it is a bad habit to use asterisk while working with columns. Always name all of them; yes, it requires some more typing, but makes things much more clear. Therefore, avoid `select request.*` and specify `select emp_deptno, ename, job, dept_deptno, dname from request` instead.

Comment: done and its corrected now, thank u

Comment: Even simpler demonstration: `select dummy, dummy from dual` is OK, but `select * from (select dummy, dummy from dual)` is not, because if you expand the `*` as `select dummy, dummy from (select dummy, dummy from dual)` then the database can't tell which one you mean in each case.

Answer (score 0):

Remove one of the duplicate `Request_id` columns (since you already have the join condition `a.request_id = c.request_id` then they must always be the same value). You can also remove the unnecessary `1=1` filter and the `SELECT` wrapping the main query:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT
       a.REQUEST_ID,
       ( SELECT full_name
         FROM   apps.per_all_people_f ppf
         WHERE  sysdate BETWEEN effective_start_date 
                        AND     effective_end_date
         AND    a.EMPLOYEE_NUMBER in (ppf.national_identifier,ppf.employee_number) 
         AND    current_employee_flag = 'Y'
       ) AS  EMPLOYEE_NUMBER,
       a.DEPARTMENT,
       a.LOCATION,
       a.PROBLEM_TYPE,
       a.PROBLEM_PRIORITY,
       a.PROBLEM_SUMMARY,
       a.PROBLEM_DATE ,
       a.CREATED_BY ,
       a.CREATION_DATE,
       a.LAST_UPDATE_DATE,
       a.LAST_UPDATE_LOGIN,
       a.LAST_UPDATED_BY,
       a.STATUS,
       a.CLOSED_DATE,
       a.ASSIGNED_TO,
       a.EXTENSION,
       'Assign' as Assign,
       ( SELECT user_name
         FROM   apps.fnd_user
         WHERE  user_id=a.created_by
       ) AS Assigned_by,
       c.FILENAME,
       c.MIME_TYPE,
       c.BLOB_CONTENT                
FROM   IT_REQUESTS a
       INNER JOIN IT_REQUESTS_ATTACH c
       ON (a.request_id = c.request_id)
WHERE  a.request_source = 'IT'
AND    a.status         = 'CLOSED'--'NEW'
ORDER BY a.PROBLEM_DATE desc
```